# is it OK if some malloc() implementation returns aligned addr by default?

Tags: c, malloc, alignment

I want to implement my own `malloc()` and `aligned_alloc()` for debugging purposes.
The question is, what problems can I face if `malloc()` will work the same as `aligned_alloc()` for `sizeof(void*)` alignment by default?

Comment: `malloc` is required by the C standard to return an address aligned for any object with fundamental alignment requirement, which includes all the integer, floating-point, enumerated, and pointer types, as well as any complete object type defined in the standard library. If it returns an address that is only aligned for a `void *` and there are fundamental-type objects in the C implementation with stricter alignment requirements (e.g., perhaps `long double`), then such `malloc` is non-conforming and could cause problems, such as alignment traps.

Comment: On the other hand, if your `malloc` returns memory stricter than required, that should not cause any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `malloc` implementations already return aligned pointers anyway. The one I know about have to: since the `((size_t *)ptr)[-1]` contains a size, it has to be aligned to be able to store a `size_t`.
That is just an implementation thing. So, afaik, there is no theory saying "it has to be aligned". But, well, there must be a way to store the allocated size, or, something that can leed to it, so that `free` knows what to deallocate.

So, there is no problem at all in the fact that `malloc` returns aligned pointers. As long as you are coherent with it. Of course, it is a waste of some bytes if people use `malloc(1)` in cascade. But, well, it would have been any way, because the "heap metadata" (the `ptr[-1]` thing) would not be negligible as they should be.

The difference with `aligned_alloc` is that you can specify the alignment, to have a stricter one than the one it provides anyway.

Comment: thanks for your reply! but, according to the man: `return a pointer to the allocated memory, which is suitably *aligned for any built-in type.*`, that point confused me... so can we claim that `malloc()` always returns pointers already aligned to `sizeof(void *)` ?

Comment: Re “So, afaik, there is no theory saying "it has to be aligned"”: C 2018 7.22.3 1 says “… The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement…” (Fundamental alignments are covered in 6.2.8 2 and cover all the ordinary types.)

Comment: Re “since the `((size_t *)ptr)[-1]` contains a size, it has to be aligned to be able to store a `size_t`”: That is faulty reasoning. A non-aligned location could be used to store a `size_t` by using `memcpy` or equivalent to copy the bytes in and out. `malloc` returns are aligned because the C standard requires it, not because choosing to store a `size_t` prior to the block requires alignment.